# Help storing color hexadecimals as an integer in Java

Tags: java, android, hex

I need to represent the hex color `#F0FFF0` in an android application (stored as an integer). I am storing this as:

```
int color = 0xF0FFF0;
```

But the color seems way off when being rendered (in fact, it's black). Am I storing the color incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you need to set the alpha too. 
ie.

`int color = 0xFFF0FFF0;`

where the first two FF represent the alpha as being completely opaque.
See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Answer (score 6):

Android uses Hex ARGB values, which are formatted as #AARRGGBB. That first pair of letters, the AA, represent the Alpha Channel. You must convert your decimal opacity values to a Hexdecimal value. Here are the steps:

**Alpha Hex Value Process**

1. Take your opacity as a decimal value and multiply it by 255. So, if you have a block that is 50% opaque the decimal value would be .5. For example: .5 x 255 = 127.5
2. The fraction won't convert to hex, so you must round your number up or down to the nearest whole number. For example: 127.5 rounds up to 128; 55.25 rounds down to 55.
3. Enter your decimal value in a decimal to hexadecimal converter, like this http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter, and convert your values
4. If you only get back a single value, prefix it with a zero. For example, if you're trying to get 5% opacity and your going through this process you'll end up with the hex value of D. Add a zero in front of it so it appears as 0D.

That's how you find the alpha channel value. I've taken the liberty to put together a list of values for you. Enjoy!

**Hex Opacity Values**

- 100% — FF
- 95% — F2
- 90% — E6
- 85% — D9
- 80% — CC
- 75% — BF
- 70% — B3
- 65% — A6
- 60% — 99
- 55% — 8C
- 50% — 80
- 45% — 73
- 40% — 66
- 35% — 59
- 30% — 4D
- 25% — 40
- 20% — 33
- 15% — 26
- 10% — 1A
- 5% — 0D
- 0% — 00

Answer (score 3):

I've always specified my colours with the alpha value, ie:

```
int color = 0xFFF0FFF0;
```

I'm not sure if the leading FF will be implicit if it's omitted however.

Answer (score 1):

Not you didn't.

You have  to add Alpha channel.

For your example is :

```
int color = 0xFFF0FFF0
```

I think it works!